# Custom user profile fields, not editable by user

Tags: 7, entities, users

I've created some custom user profile fields but I don't want to let the user change those fields when he is editing his profile. These fields should only be changed by the site admin.

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try looking at the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.  Simply don't allow editing of your specific fields for the role that the registering/registered user has.